# QList of QScopedPointers

Tags: qt, containers, qt5, smart-pointers, qscopedpointer

I'm trying to store QScopedPointers in a QList.

I found this comment

> One can also use QList >. – Kuba Ober Jan 14 '14 at 18:17

(first comment on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21120575/3095014)

and this post https://forum.qt.io/topic/59338/solved-qlist-of-qscopedpointers which implies that this should work. But if I try to compile the code of the second link, I'm getting this errors:

```
E:\Qt\Qt5Enterprise\5.5\msvc2013\include\QtCore/qlist.h(404) : error C2248: 'QScopedPointer<Label,QScopedPointerDeleter<T>>::QScopedPointer' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QScopedPointer<Label,QScopedPointerDeleter<T>>'
    with
    [
        T=Label
    ]
    E:\Qt\Qt5Enterprise\5.5\msvc2013\include\QtCore/qscopedpointer.h(170) : see declaration of 'QScopedPointer<Label,QScopedPointerDeleter<T>>::QScopedPointer'
    with
    [
        T=Label
    ]
    E:\Qt\Qt5Enterprise\5.5\msvc2013\include\QtCore/qlist.h(403) : while compiling class template member function 'void QList<QScopedPointer<Label,QScopedPointerDeleter<T>>>::node_construct(QList<QScopedPointer<T,QScopedPointerDeleter<T>>>::Node *,const QScopedPointer<T,QScopedPointerDeleter<T>> &)'
    with
    [
        T=Label
    ]
    E:\Qt\Qt5Enterprise\5.5\msvc2013\include\QtCore/qlist.h(553) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void QList<QScopedPointer<Label,QScopedPointerDeleter<T>>>::node_construct(QList<QScopedPointer<T,QScopedPointerDeleter<T>>>::Node *,const QScopedPointer<T,QScopedPointerDeleter<T>> &)' being compiled
    with
    [
        T=Label
    ]
    E:\Qt\Qt5Enterprise\5.5\msvc2013\include\QtCore/qlist.h(794) : while compiling class template member function 'QList<QScopedPointer<Label,QScopedPointerDeleter<T>>>::~QList(void)'
    with
    [
        T=Label
    ]
    ..\tableview_row_dnd\main.cpp(13) : see reference to function template instantiation 'QList<QScopedPointer<Label,QScopedPointerDeleter<T>>>::~QList(void)' being compiled
    with
    [
        T=Label
    ]
    ..\tableview_row_dnd\main.cpp(20) : see reference to class template instantiation 'QList<QScopedPointer<Label,QScopedPointerDeleter<T>>>' being compiled
    with
    [
        T=Label
    ]
E:\Qt\Qt5Enterprise\5.5\msvc2013\include\QtCore/qlist.h(405) : error C2248: 'QScopedPointer<Label,QScopedPointerDeleter<T>>::QScopedPointer' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QScopedPointer<Label,QScopedPointerDeleter<T>>'
    with
    [
        T=Label
    ]
    E:\Qt\Qt5Enterprise\5.5\msvc2013\include\QtCore/qscopedpointer.h(170) : see declaration of 'QScopedPointer<Label,QScopedPointerDeleter<T>>::QScopedPointer'
    with
    [
        T=Label
    ]
```

Why isn't this working for me?

Comment: Show the relevant part of your code.

Comment: As I wrote: It is the exact code of the question in this post https://forum.qt.io/topic/59338/solved-qlist-of-qscopedpointers (without the foo function)

Answer (score 15):

Values stored in Qt containers should be of assignable data types. That means they should have a default constructor, a copy constructor, and an assignment operator.

`QScopedPointer` has its copy constructor and assignment operator disabled. You can't assign two pointers to each other, but you can explicitly transfer the ownership of the underlying raw pointer using `QScopedPointer::reset`, `QScopedPointer::swap` or `QScopedPointer::take`.

[At some point](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/61743/) a move constructor and a move assignment operator were added to `QScopedPointer`. New move semantics made this possible:

```
QList<QScopedPointer<Label>> mLabels;
mLabels.append(QScopedPointer<Label>(new Label));
```

Here a temporary value is added to a list and the new list item is created using the move constructor.

[Later](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/64428/) they reverted that change:

> Adding a move contructor to QScopedPointer makes no sense, because
>   moving means 'escaping the scope', which breaks the fundamental point
>   of QScopedPointer.

If you really want to have a list of smart pointers, you can use `QSharedPointer` which is assignable or `std::unique_ptr` which supports move semantics.

And if you talk about tracking lifetime of `QObjects` subclasses and especially widgets, I would suggest to use Qt child-parent mechanism rather than smart pointers.

Comment: Note that the requirement on assignable data types is extremely suboptimal when compared to the STL containers. In a couple of cases (for instance: default constructability) the requirement arises from poor implementation. Workaround: use STL containers instead of Qt ones if you really want a vector of `unique_ptr`.