# Is it possible to have a QList of QScopedPointer of some abstract class?

Tags: c++, qt, abstract-class, qscopedpointer

I want to have a `QList` or `QVector` in a class that it has a constant number of element type `QScopedPointer< SomeAbstractClass >`. I could easily use something like this:

```
QList<QScopedPointer<SomeClass> listClass;
listClass.append(QScopedPointer<SomeClass>(new SomeClass()));
```

But in `QScopedPointer`, copy constructor is disabled and we can't instantiate an abstract class.

Off course I could easily use `QSharedPointer` but for some reasons I don't want to do that, so what can I do?

Edit:
Here is my sample code, and I got this error:

```
class someAbsClass{
    public:
        someAbsClass(){}
        virtual void fcn()=0;
    };

    class someClass : public someAbsClass{
    public:
        someClass(){}
        void fcn(){
            std::cout << "fcn" << std::endl;
        }
    };


    int main(){
        QVector<QScopedPointer<someAbsClass> > VectorPtrAbss(1);
        VectorPtrAbss[0].reset(new someClass());
    }

error: 'QScopedPointer<T, Cleanup>::QScopedPointer(const QScopedPointer<T, Cleanup>&) [with T = someAbsClass; Cleanup = QScopedPointerDeleter<someAbsClass>]' is private
 Q_DISABLE_COPY(QScopedPointer)
                ^
```

Comment: Regarding instantiating an abstract class, you should instantiate a *concrete* class, one that inherits from the abstract class.

Comment: Also, if you say you have "some reasons" you don't want something, you might want to elaborate. *Why* don't you want to use `QSharedPointer`? And what is the actual problem you are trying to solve by using a list of `QScopedPointer`? ([Related reading about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).)

Comment: QScopedPointer is designed to solve another problem, but you can use std::unique_ptr which supports move semantic.

Comment: I think <code>QScopedPointer </code> is designed for membership class pointers that only valid in the scope of every object of a class or function. In my problem I read from some config file a <code>QScopedPointer</code> variable and pass it to a <code>QList</code> then destroy that variable, somehow swap ownership of the variable. Off course I could do that if my <code>SomeClass></code> wasn't an abstract class. Any idea?

Comment: I think base on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761327/qlist-of-qscopedpointers), I simply can't use any move semantic with QScopedPointer!, So I must use another smart pointer like QSharedPointer.