# Using a QScopedArrayPointer of an abstract class?

Tags: qt, smart-pointers, qscopedpointer

Recently Qt had made some changes and we can't semantically move `QScopedPointer` so we can't have a  `QList< QScopedPointer< SomeClass> >` , based on my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761327/qlist-of-qscopedpointers).

My second solution was using `QScopedArrayPointer`. But we cannot use these containers for abstract classes, which was my original problem. Is there any other way to use some list of `QScopedPointer`  for abstract classes?

Comment: Why won't you switch to `QSharedPointer` if what you need is not possible with `QScopedPointer`?

Comment: I actually did use a QSharedPointer for my problem, but I'm seeking for a more best solution! because conceptually a QScopedPointer is sufficient for my problem and I don't want a QSharedPointer.

Comment: ok, but you can't use `QScopedPtr` as you already found out. So you don't have many choices. You can use raw pointers if the objects you store there are inherited from `QObject` — just pass a parent to them and you are done. Or, you can switch to `std::vector<std::unique_ptr>`.

Comment: so, I think it's a bug or a loss for Qt. Because I think concept of QScopedPointer should allow us to have a QList<QScopedPointer<someAbseClass> >, but it seems not.

Comment: @JonHarper no I don't think it's for deleter function. Because of Q_DISABLED_COPY, we can't copy QList of QSCopedPointer!!

Comment: You can call it a drawback but it is certainly not a bug. Anyway, you are not forced to use it so if it doesn't suit your needs just switch to another solution.

Comment: @JonHarper Yeah you right, thank you :)

Comment: Move semantics have been discussed before. It's pedantic, but the decision was made not to add them because it goes against the name and original intent of `QScopedPointer`. It would be nice if the devs would add a `QUniquePointer` (and deprecate `QScopedPointer` at Qt6).

Comment: I see that was discussed in an answer to your question. Oops.